# Synchronize 2 Databases

Tags: mysql, database-replication, data-synchronization

I have 2 MySQL databases with same table structure but on different servers. I want to make it that when the database on server 1 is updated, the database on the server 2 is also updated, and vice versa. Can I do it in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is two-way replication. You can read up on why not to do it with mysql [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-replication.html#qandaitem-B-13-1-5) If you must, mysql supports it, but it doesn't guarantee atomicity of the operations involved, which will lead to inconsistencies at some point. 
I stronly advise against this.

Answer (score 0):

It's risky to do bidirectional replication, because MySQL replication is asynchronous.  Below is a link to a webinar describing the risks.  The recording of the webinar is free to view, but you need to register to view it.  The slides are free to download.

[The Hazards of Multi-writing in a Dual-Master Setup](http://www.percona.com/webinars/hazards-multi-writing-dual-master-setup)

The solution to this problem is [Percona XtraDB Cluster](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtradb-cluster), which is basically MySQL enhanced with synchronous, multi-way replication technology.  You can have any number of servers in a cluster, and you can write changes to any of these servers.  The changes are propagated to all other nodes in the cluster synchronously, greatly reducing the risks.

Answer (score -1):

You can Have DATABASE REPLICATION. See [this link](http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication) 
it gives hints on how to do database replications.

Comment: From what i understand, Frogie asked for the updates to be propagated in both directions, which the link you gave doesn't describe.

Comment: @Max in the link i post i did not say that it has hints of updates to be propagated in both directions what i stated there is that it has hints on HOW TO DO DATABASE REPLICATION.